# th:replace doesn't work well with th:with in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

According to *Thymeleaf* [`docs`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#including-template-fragments)

> Fragments can include any th:* attributes. These attributes will be evaluated once the fragment is included into the target template (the one with the th:insert/**th:replace** attribute), and they will be able to reference any context variables defined in this target template.

My Fragment

```
<div th:fragment="link">
    <a th:href="@{${url}}"><span th:inline="text">[[${text}]]</span></a>
</div>
```

This is how I include it.

```
<div th:replace="fragments/common :: link" th:with="url='www.google.com', text='Click Me'"></div>
```

The html i get

```
<a href="">
    <span>null</span>
</a>
```

However the same works fine with `th:include` and gives me following HTML.

```
<a href="www.google.com">
    <span>Click Me</span>
</a>
```

Why `th:replace` ***doesn't*** work while `th:inlcude` works fine?

**NOTE:** `th:insert` is out of scope because i am using `Thymeleaf v2.1.5`

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that `th:replace` actually removes current tag so you lose every attribute you had there, but get all the attributes from fragment. And in your case this means that you never defined any `th:with` variable  in the scope.`th:include` works the opposite way. You loose fragment tag, but keep everything defined in layout.

Consider this fragment:

```html
<fragmenttag th:fragment="link" style="background-color: red">...</fragmenttag>
```

And layout:

```html
<layouttag th:include="fragments/common :: link" style="font-size: 250%;"/>
<layouttag th:replace="fragments/common :: link" style="font-size: 250%;"/>
```

The result is:

```html
<layouttag style="font-size: 250%;">Some Text</layouttag>
<fragmenttag style="background-color: red">Some Text</fragmenttag>
```

If you want to use `th:replace`, because you have some important attributes in fragment, you can define everything you need in some parent tag in layout.

```html
<body th:with="url='www.google.com', text='Click Me'">
    <div th:replace="fragments/common :: link" ></div>
</body>
```

---

You are referencing documentation in your post:

> Fragments can include any th:* attributes. These attributes will be
>   evaluated once the fragment is included into the target template (the
>   one with the th:insert/th:replace attribute), and they will be able to
>   reference any context variables defined in this target template.

And i don't see any contradiction here, because this part of the documentation is about th:* attributes **inside a fragment**.

> Fragments (th:fragment part) can include any th:* attributes.

And in your question you are talking  about loosing th:* attributes defined in **target template**. But anyway, this part is quite strait that you perform inclusion logic first

> These attributes will be evaluated **once the fragment is included**

There is nothing here that lets you assume that you will get everything you defined in target template or fragments main tag, because both of them can be replaced depending on witch inclusion strategy you are going to use (th:insert/th:replace).

So you defined `th:with="url='www.google.com', text='Click Me'"` attribute, but it was never included in the end result template because you selected `th:replace` inclusion strategy, so th:with attribute was never evaluated and you got no `url` and `text` variables in scope. No contradiction here.

Comment: Yes but accroding to the official documentation `th:replace` should work. Shouldn't it?

Comment: @AbdullahKhan it works just like described in http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#difference-between-thinclude-and-threplace What part of official documentation are you referencing?

Comment: the one i posted in the question!

Comment: @AbdullahKhan i think the part you quote in your question is taking about how fragment works and that you can use th:* attributes inside the fragment. like `<fragmenttag th:fragment="link" >You can use any th:* attributes here inside the fragment and they will see main template scope</fragmenttag>` Basically this part of documentation is saying that theamleaf will perform `th:insert/th:replace` first like described in the link i provided above and then evaluate everything as 1 big template with common scope

Comment: @AbdullahKhan _These attributes will be evaluated **once the fragment is included** into the target template_ But if you use `th:replace` you loose all the attributes from your tag in main template layout during the inclusion process.

Comment: Yes i get it th:replace replaces the parent tag that is calling the fragments. But this contradicts with what they have mentioned in the docs i posted.

Comment: @AbdullahKhan i updated my post a bit, and actually don't see any contradiction here. You highlighted `th:replace` part in your question, but it is just a clarification of the side of the relation `target template` represents.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a similar (not same) issue thank the one mentined in [this post](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/th-replace-and-th-include-behave-differently-td4028063.html)

As a workaround for this issue you can still use `th:include` and then remove the extra `div` by using `th:remove="tag"`, something like:

```
<div th:include="fragments/common :: link" th:with="url='www.google.com', text='Click Me'" th:remove="tag"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i am aware of this.